# Flutter: Mensagem de erro Could not update files on device: HttpException

Tags: android, flutter

Olá, estou estudando Flutter e recentemente tive um problema, quando tentei executar meu projeto com `Flutter run` recebi a mensagem de erro:

**Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:50365/h3iViYQmEC4=/**

Tentei com emulador e com meu próprio celular porém recebo o mesmo erro.

O estranho é que quando eu crio um App em Flutter novo ele funciona, consigo fazer todas as modificações porem se eu parar e tentar executar novamente o erro aparece e o App não roda.

Já tentei reiniciar os dispositivos. `Flutter clean` `Flutter doctor` [Exibe que está tudo certo]

Até meus app antigos que tinha feito pra estudar acontece a mesma coisa, sendo que estavam funcionando.

Mensagem completa com Flutter run:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Estou usando Android.
- Mensagem que aparece no celular é a padrão 'O app parou de funcionar, deseja encerrar?'

Comment: Uma dica, tente usar caminhos pro teu projeto que não possuam caracteres especiais e nem espaço, por exemplo: D:\Projetos\Projetos flutter\teste **(Errado)**... D:\Projetos\ProjetosFlutter\teste **(certo)**.

Answer (score 1):

**[RESOLVIDO]** - O problema era uma fonte externa que eu estava importando que aparentemente se corrompeu, percebi que aparece uma mensagem :

Eu retirei todo lugar que eu usava ela e voltou ao normal.